# Custom #ajax "Add another" button only adds 1

Tags: forms, ajax, 8

This form consists of 1 textfield, and 1 ajax button.

I'm trying to make it add another text field with each click.

It works for the first one, to get a total of 2 text fields. I cannot get more than 2 to appear though.

I suspect the dom is being updated, but not the form. So the subsequent callbacks add an element based on the original form build.

I'm not sure how to approach this in Drupal 8. Any insight would be appreciated.

Here is my form control

```
<?php
...
class MyModuleForm extends FormBase {
  ...
  public function buildForm(array $form, array &$form_state) {
    $form['foo'] = array(
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="foo-replace">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>'
    );
    $form['foo'][0] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield'
    );
    $form['add'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#name' => 'add',
      '#value' => t('Add'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => array($this, 'addMore'),
        'wrapper' => 'foo-replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
    );
    return $form;
  }

  public function addMore(array $form, array &$form_state) {
    $form['foo'][] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield'
    );
    return $form['foo'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent more time with `WidgetBase` from the field module.

The solution was to define a `#submit` handler on the ajax button. In the submit handler, set `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE`. This will allow the form to rebuild with `buildForm`.

Based on core code comments, this is the proper way to gracefully degrade so it works without JS as well. I like it, no need read `$form_state` for `triggering_element`.

Note that adding `$form_state['rebuild']` to `submitForm` will not trigger a rebuild from an ajax button. (from my testing anyway)

Once the form is rebuilding, it's like D7. You can add the handler logic in `buildForm` as Mołot pointed out, and return just the target element in your callback.

Here's the final working form:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;

class MyModuleForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'mymodule_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, array &$form_state) {
    // Initialize the counter if it hasn't been set.
    if (!isset($form_state['fields'])) {
      // Nested this deep to avoid conflicts with other modules
      $form_state['fields'] = array(
        'mymodule' => array(
          'foo' => array(
            'items_count' => 1
          )
        )
      );
    }

    $max = $form_state['fields']['mymodule']['foo']['items_count'];
    $form['foo'] = array(
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="foo-replace">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>'
    );

    // Add elements that don't already exist
    for ($delta = 0; $delta < $max; $delta++) {
      if (!isset($form['foo'][$delta])) {
        $element = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield'
        );
        $form['foo'][$delta] = $element;
      }
    }

    $form['add'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#name' => 'add',
      '#value' => t('Add'),
      '#submit' => array(array($this, 'addMoreSubmit')),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => array($this, 'addMoreCallback'),
        'wrapper' => 'foo-replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
    );
    return $form;
  }

  public function addMoreSubmit(array &$form, array &$form_state) {
    $form_state['fields']['mymodule']['foo']['items_count']++;
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  }

  public function addMoreCallback(array &$form, array &$form_state) {
    return $form['foo'];
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, array &$form_state) {

  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, array &$form_state) {
  }
}
```

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type Drupal\\Core\\Form\\FormState as array

Comment: @AnD the error is because it needs to be FormStateInterface $form_state not array $form_state

Answer (score 4):

You made a common mistake. In Form API, `['#ajax']['callback']` has only 2 purposes:

- Make one-time changes to form, that are *not* meant to persist form reload, submit or second Ajax request. Good example is adding some classes to freshly modified element.
- Return proper part of the form.

To have persistent changes, you need to keep the number of elements you want somewhere, for example in `$form_state`, and add them in form builder function, `buildForm` in your case.

My approach would be to check `$form_state['triggering_element']` to see if it was your Ajax button to invoke form building, and if so, increase counter. Then simply `for($i = 0; $i < $element_counter; ++$i)` to add required number of elements.

Comment: Are you 100% on your answer? I tried your suggestions before asking my question here. `buildForm` only seemed to execute when the page loads. I also tried `processForm`, which did execute when the callback was triggered, but I did not have access to `triggering_element` from that one. In D7, the equivalent to buildForm() executes with the callback. I'm just trying to figure out how to accomplish this in D8.

Comment: @Coder1 I am sure about approach, for exact sample see Mathankumar's answer as I don't have Drupal 8 at hand. I admit that buildForm not executed on ajax calls is a bit of mystery to me, but **I'm 100% sure callback is not the place** for persistent changes.

Comment: Understood, and not how it works in D7 either. That's just where I ended up because `buildForm` isn't triggering with the callback and code samples are a great place to start.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the nuts and bolts of this answer have changed as the Drupal 8 APIs have evolved and "solidified". While the general approach of manipulating the form works. The $form_state param can not be used as an array, and must be an object of type FormStateInterface. The method signatures should look like:

`public function buildForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state)`

The $form_state class also has methods getting for setting arbitrary data. Simply,  `$form_state->get(property, value)`  and  `$form_state->set(property, value)`  in this context. Here's a link to get started with the set method: [FormStateInterface::set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3Aset/8). And a link to a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ethanhinson/ec7c343d8b804824806f)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get that to work. It seems like it's not supposed to. See this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215784).